# Flutter app (iOS side) starts with a white screen when I add FCM code in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

This app was working normally, so, I want to deliver notifications through FCM and added this code : [Firebase Documentation](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/509d48f2c217da0115d5f3d86765b9d8d4251060/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L62-L97) at my appDelegate.swift and now I run the app and it only shows a white screen.

In the console there are no error and no warnings... What I have to do to solve it?

Comment: Why are you following native iOS documentation for a Flutter app? Try [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/) instead. iOS-specific setup can be found [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration).

Comment: Faced the same issue sometime ago but now its fixed and I don't know how!
P.S: Could not launch my app on ios due some other issue.

Comment: You do not need to follow native iOS documentation in order to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging in a Flutter app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating FirebaseMessaging to 8.0.0 dev-14 solved my problem.

If anyone reading this has the same problem I suggest to check AGAIN and CAREFULLY all the steps listed here [Documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration) because probably you forgot one thing or another, in my case, in firebase Apns the team id was wrong...